# How to find xml node id using SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column called `content` in application table that contains XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<XmlData>
    <dataitem id="Hello" value="true" />
</XmlData>
```

This value in one row same like another row and so on

My problem is that now I want to find which rows have an `id` attribute with the value of `Hello`.

How can I do this?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to study [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) if you want to process XML data with SQL Server. Find below one of possible solutions:

```
-- Here is your data
declare @YourTable table (
    YourXmlField XML
    )

insert into @YourTable values (
'<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<XmlData>
<dataitem id="Hello" value="true" />
</XmlData>'
)

-- Here is solution
select x.xmldata.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
from @YourTable t
cross apply t.YourXmlField.nodes('/XmlData/dataitem') x(xmldata)
```